# Vertical align of inputs

Tags: html, css

This is my code:  http://jsfiddle.net/jfxrykw7/

```
<form class="search">
<input type="text" class="input text" placeholder="Keyword">
<input type="A" class="input text" placeholder="B">
<input type="submit" class="btn submit">
</form>

.input {
margin:0;
border: 1px solid #c8d1d7;
font-size: 14px;
padding: 10px 12px;
font-weight: 300;
border-radius: 3px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.input_form {
width: 100%;
display: block;
}

.search {
width: 728px;
margin: 0 auto;
}


.search .text {
   width: 300px; 
   margin-right: 30px; ;
}

.search .submit {
background-size: 20px 20px;
background-image: url('http://www.clker.com/cliparts/n/U/H/1/H/u/search-icon-white-one-hi.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
font-size: 0;
height: 38px;
width: 60px;
}
```

I can't understand why the submit button sits lower than the other inputs? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The clue is in your question title: [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

Comment: Ok, so should I apply a baseline middle or top, or does it not matter. And does it need to be on input and submit or just input?

Comment: If you want to ignore the `vertical-align`, you *could* set the submit to `float: right;` ... http://jsfiddle.net/jfxrykw7/8/

Comment: *Ok, so should I apply a baseline middle or top* - Only you know the answer to that one, where do *you* want them vertically aligned? If this is your complete form markup then my choice would be `form.search input{ vertical-align:middle; }`

Comment: @George:that's why added both in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just  add

```
.submit{

    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[**FIXED DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/86gqx59z/)

**OR**

```
.submit{

    vertical-align:top;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3o426g5x/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could add `vertical-align:top` on submit button:

```
.search .submit {
background-size: 20px 20px;
background-image: url('http://www.clker.com/cliparts/n/U/H/1/H/u/search-icon-white-one-hi.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
vertical-align: top;
font-size: 0;
height: 38px;
width: 60px;
}
```